# Changing footmark in footmisc

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, memoir, footmisc

No way to have ragged right footnotes in memoir. 
Tried using `ragged2e`, redefining `\@makefntext` and yes, it makes the text ragged, but puts the footnote mark way to the left.

The only way to obtain ragged right footnotes I have found is to load `\usepackage[ragged,hang]{footmisc}`

But how can I change the footnote mark from superscript to normal number followed by a dot? In the following MWE comment the footmisc loading and uncomment the other lines to see what I want to achieve.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,italian]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ragged,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%% memoir footnotes
% \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.7em}
% \setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
% \footmarkstyle{#1.\hfill}
% \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
trovate\footnote{Il progetto One Laptop Per Child si prefigge di fornire a ogni bambino, soprattutto nelle aree più disagiate del pianeta, degli speciali laptop economici e a basso consumo, robusti e semplici da utilizzare, in modo che i bambini possano diventare artefici della loro propria formazione} sul mio sito.\footnote{Il mio sito è: \href{http://mariovalle.name}{mariovalle.name} e le pagine dedicate a Montessori sono: \href{http://mariovalle.name/montessori}{mariovalle.name/montessori}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following definition in the preamble to make the footnote content ragged right.

```
\renewcommand{\makefootmark}[1]{\raggedright%
  \leavevmode
  \parindent \footparindent\noindent
  \leftskip\footmarksep\relax
  \advance\leftskip \footmarkwidth \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip\relax
  \makefootmarkhook\relax
  \footfootmark #1}
```

I have now added `\raggedright` at the beginning of the macro `\makefootmark`.

The MWE will now becomes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,italian]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[ragged]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% memoir footnotes
\renewcommand{\makefootmark}[1]{\raggedright%
  \leavevmode
  \parindent \footparindent\noindent
  \leftskip\footmarksep\relax
  \advance\leftskip \footmarkwidth \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip\relax
  \makefootmarkhook\relax
  \footfootmark #1}
 \setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.7em}
 \setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
 \footmarkstyle{#1.\hfill}
 \setlength{\footnotesep}{0.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

trovate\footnote{Il progetto One Laptop Per Child si prefigge di
fornire a ogni bambino, soprattutto nelle aree più disagiate del
pianeta, degli speciali laptop economici e a basso consumo, robusti e
semplici da utilizzare, in modo che i bambini possano diventare
artefici della loro propria formazione} sul mio sito.\footnote{Il mio
sito è: \href{http://mariovalle.name}{mariovalle.name} e le pagine
dedicate a Montessori sono:
\href{http://mariovalle.name/montessori}{mariovalle.name/montessori}}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Note: I have now added some `\blindtext` to check whether there is any change appeared when long paragraph were added to the document.

The footnote will now appear as:

[image]

I have not used `footmisc` package for this solution.

Comment: Perfect! It solves my problem beautifully without leaving `memoir`. The `footmisc` solution works, but I was not able to change the footnote mark from superscript to a normal character.

Comment: Jagath, you can send this beautiful solution to daleif@math.au.dk for inclusion in the memoir manual, section C (Sniplets).

Answer (score 1):

There is hook that you can use to insert code in footnotes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,italian]{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\makefootmarkhook}{\raggedright}
\begin{document}
trovate\footnote{Il progetto One Laptop Per Child si prefigge di fornire a ogni bambino, soprattutto nelle aree più disagiate del pianeta, degli speciali laptop economici e a basso consumo, robusti e semplici da utilizzare, in modo che i bambini possano diventare artefici della loro propria formazione} sul mio sito.\footnote{Il mio sito è: \href{http://mariovalle.name}{mariovalle.name} e le pagine dedicate a Montessori sono: \href{http://mariovalle.name/montessori}{mariovalle.name/montessori}}
\end{document}
```

[image]